# Professor Halfbrain and the fantasy knight

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics, graph-theory

Professor Halfbrain owns a 99×99 board for fantasy chess, whose rows are numbered consecutively from 1 to 99 and whose columns are also numbered consecutively from 1 to 99.
A fantasy knight can jump from a square in the -th column to any square in the -th row (and can jump to no other square); note that if the knight can jump from square  to square , then this does not mean that it can also jump from square  to square .

The professor claims that there exists a closed fantasy knight tour on the chessboard that makes the knight visit every square exactly once, and in the end takes it back to its starting square.

> **Question:** Is Halfbrain's claim indeed true, or has the professor once again made one of his mathematical blunders?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes there is a solution with a very simple strategy:

Start in (1,1).
Always go the right most square that's unvisited

I'll try to illustrate it. I checked it by hand on an 9x9 board and a very nice pattern emerges that makes it clear it works on any X by X  board.

|  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **1** | 1 | 79 | 74 | 67 | 58 | 47 | 34 | 19 | 2 |
| **2** | 81 | 80 | 77 | 72 | 65 | 56 | 45 | 32 | 17 |
| **3** | 78 | 76 | 75 | 70 | 63 | 54 | 43 | 30 | 15 |
| **4** | 73 | 71 | 69 | 68 | 61 | 52 | 41 | 28 | 13 |
| **5** | 66 | 64 | 62 | 60 | 59 | 50 | 39 | 26 | 11 |
| **6** | 57 | 55 | 53 | 51 | 49 | 48 | 37 | 24 | 9 |
| **7** | 46 | 44 | 42 | 40 | 38 | 36 | 35 | 22 | 7 |
| **8** | 33 | 31 | 29 | 27 | 25 | 23 | 21 | 20 | 5 |
| **9** | 18 | 16 | 14 | 12 | 10 | 8 | 6 | 4 | 3 |

Answer (score 22):

Let $(x,y)$ be the square in row $x$, column $y$, so that a fantasy knight can move from $(x,y)$ to $(y,z)$.  A closed tour is described by a cyclic sequence $$x_0,x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_{99^2-1},x_{99^2}=x_0,$$ where the knight moves from $(x_0,x_1)$ to $(x_1,x_2)$, then to $(x_2,x_3)$, and so on up to $(x_{99^2-1},x_0)$, then finally back to $(x_0,x_1)$. Each square is visited exactly once, so this is an example of a de Bruijn sequence (specifically a $99$-ary de Bruijn sequence of order $2$). De Bruijn sequences are known to exist ([the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence#Construction) describes a construction), so Halfbrain's claim is true.

Some other puzzles on this site have answers involving de Bruijn sequences (I found [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22903/arranging-all-the-dominos/22904#22904), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/22842/one-beer-too-many/22843#22843), [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9397/shortest-number-containing-the-numbers-1-100/9399#9399), and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16698/unique-licence-plates/16706#16706)).